# How to calculate percentage of certain value in column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a table:

| country | ID | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | a1 | upload |
| US | a1 | delete |
| US | a1 | delete |
| US | a2 | upload |
| US | a2 | upload |
| US | a2 | delete |
| IT | k2 | upload |
| IT | k2 | upload |
| IT | k2 | delete |

I need to get data frame with unique countries, count number of unique ID's in it and average percent of "delete" value in type among each ID in country. So desired table must look like:

| country | ID_cnt | delete_perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2 | 0.5 |
| IT | 1 | 0.33 |

Its 0.498 since for ID a1, its 0.66; and for a2, it's 0.33; s (0.66 + 0.33)/2 = 0.5

How to do that with Python?

Comment: `df.assign(type=df['type'].eq('delete')).groupby('country').agg({'ID':'nunique', 'type':'mean'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `agg`:

```
>>> df.assign(delete_perc=df['type'].eq('delete')).groupby('country', as_index=False).agg({'ID': 'nunique', 'delete_perc': 'mean'})
  country  ID  delete_perc
0      IT   1     0.333333
1      US   2     0.500000
>>>
```

Or possible with `value_counts` and `normalize=True`:

```
>>> df.groupby('country', as_index=False).agg(ID=('ID', 'nunique'), delete_perc=('type', lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True)['delete']))
  country  ID  delete_perc
0      IT   1     0.333333
1      US   2     0.500000
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For table manipulation in Python, we often use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package. You first need to create a `pandas.DataFrame` object and then, for your use case, use the `groupby` and `agg` operations.

There is a complete example:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """country ID type
US a1 upload
US a1 delete
US a1 delete
US a2 upload
US a2 upload
US a2 delete
IT k2 upload
IT k2 upload
IT k2 delete
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=" ")

country_stats = (
    df
    .groupby('country', as_index=False)
    .agg(
        ID=('ID', 'nunique'),
        delete_perc=('type', lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True)['delete']))
)
```

The `country_stats` DataFrame now contains the desired output:

```py
    country ID  delete_perc
0   IT  1   0.333333
1   US  2   0.500000
```